# How to delete a Blog based on admin_id in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apiato

I am developing crud operations for blog ,i want to delete the blog based on the id for that i write one api which is responsible for deleting the Blog based on the admin_id to the blog ID ,it's not deleting the blog , i am not getting where did i mistaken please help me to fix this issue..

`BlogsContainer.php`

```
public function deleteBlog(DeeleteBlogRequest $request){
    $delete=app(DeleteBlogAction::class)->run($request);
    return $this->noContent();
   }
```

`DeeleteBlogrequest.php`

```
  public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

`DeleteBlogAction.php`

```
 public function run(DeeleteBlogRequest $request)
    {
        // $var = app(Task::class)->run($arg1, $arg2);
        $delete=app(DeleteBlogTask::class)->run($request);
        return $delete;
    }
```

`DeleteBlogTask.php`

```
class DeleteBlogTask extends Task
{
    protected BlogsModel $repository;
    public function __construct(BlogsModel $repository)
    {
        $this->repository=$repository;
        // ..
    }

    public function run($id)
    {
        $book=BlogsModel::findOrFail($id);
        $book->admin_id=BlogsModel::where('admin_id',$book)->value('admin_id');
       
        $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        $details = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->toArray();
        $Admin_id = $details["sub"];
  
        if($Admin_id==$book->admin_id){
        return $trash=$this->repository->delete($id);
        // return $trash;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `DeleteBlogAction` you are passing the request to `run` method of `DeleteBlogTask` class. But the `run` method of `DeleteBlogTask` expects an id.

So either do `app(DeleteBlogTask::class)->run($request->input('id');` in `DeleteBlogAction` or change the signature of the `run` method of `DeleteBlogTask`, so that it expects a request. Then inside the `run` method you can get the id from reqeust.

Comment: it's not deleting in my DB